# How to retrieve the last 2 items of a list in erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm looking for a function that will retrieve the last two elements of a list in erlang.

I've tried

```
lists:nthtail( lists:length(List) - 2, List)
```

without luck, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [length/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#length-1) instead of lists:length/1 which doesn't not exist:

```
1> L = [1,2,3,4].
[1,2,3,4]
2> lists:nthtail(length(L)-2, L).
[3,4]
```

Or you can use [lists:reverse/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#reverse-1) and pattern matching:

```
1> L = [1,2,3,4].
[1,2,3,4]
2> [A, B | _] = lists:reverse(L).
[4,3,2,1]
3> A.
4
4> B.
3
```

Answer (score 6):

Yet another way how to do it:

```
last_two([A, B] = L) -> L;
last_two([_|L]) -> last_two(L).
```

It will make less garbage on heap than:

```
[B, A | _] = lists:reverse(L), [A, B].
```